# How to give standard users the ability to run task manager as a admin (windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-8.1, administrator, task-manager, standard-user

Is there a way to give a standard user the ability to run task manager as a admin without allowing the user to run anything else as an admin?(Right now, I have to run command prompt with admin privileges,enter the admin password in the window that pops up and then type in taskmgr to run task manager as admin. Is there a way to shorten this process?)

Comment: I will edit this if I must, but I am a little busy sometimes so I won't be able to make this question more clear very quickly. (Within 24 hours I will have to to edit the question.)

Comment: Short answer. No. If they can run Task Manager as Admin, they can launch ANY TASK as admin. :) If you're annoyed by those prompts, why not turn down UAC's prompting?

Comment: I just want to give the standard user a few rights, such as running task manager as admin, but nothing else, is that impossible?

Comment: They should be able to start Task Manager without a prompt, they just won't be able to see or interact with any processes other than their own. To do that, they'd need system administrator rights.

Comment: I would want to let standard users start task manager with admin rights but nothing else with admin rights.

Comment: @John You want to let standard users just start task manager and handle their own processes, not granting full admin rights, like Windows 7? If so `set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER&& start "" taskmgr` might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, if you could do that, the whole Windows security system would be useless.

As soon as the user has access to the first elevated process, he could start many other elevated processes and do anything on the machine.

The whole point of being a standard user is to not be able to do certain things.

Just keep your elevated command line open and run programs from there, or use a different elevated launcher, that means you are only asked for the admin password once per session.

Comment: An administrator can use a scheduled task for this. If you're logged on as an elevated administrator, you can create a task that runs interactively "with highest privileges", i.e. elevated with high integrity. schtasks.exe can manually run the task without a prompt for consent, even from the administrator's UAC-restricted standard logon.

Comment: This used to be possible with the old version of task manager. So security isn't really the cause here, but rather, they removed this feature.